# Convert csv to nested json format using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

Below  is the csv file which needs to be converted to nested json form. I was able to get the details for individual servers in json form but was unable to convert it into nested form. There are 20 more parameters in the csv file but I have added only 6 parameters.

```
    ,How many servers are required?*  ,3,,,
    
    ,Server Type,AWS,,,
    
    ,,,,,
    
    ,,,Server 1,Server 2,Server 3
    
    ,,,,,
    
    1,OS Type*,,Windows,Unix,Windows
    
    ,,,,,
    
    2,OS Version*,,Windows Server 2019,RHEL 
    7.9,Windows Server 2019
    
    ,,,,,
    
    ,,,,,
    
    3,Environment Tags ,,,,
    
    ,Name,,A,B,C
    
    ,Contact*,,abc@gmail.com,abc@gmail.com,a
    bc@gmail.com
    
    ,Owner,,ABC,EFG,HIJ
    
    ,,,,,
    
    4,EC2 Instance Type*,,t2.large,t2.large,
    t3.small
    
    ,,,,,
    
    5,Server environment*,,Non-production,No
    n-production,Non-production
    
    ,,,,,
    
    6,AWS Region*,,USEast_NorthVirginia,APAC
    _Singapore,USWest_Oregon
```

expected output:

```
{
"How many servers required" : 3,
"server type": "AWS"

"Server1":{

   "Build_data": { 
  
      "OSType": "Windows",
      "OSVersion": "Windows Server 2019",
      "EnvironmentTags": 
       {
         "Name": "sasaasasa",
         "Contact": "abc@gmail.com",
         "Owner": "NA",
        }
      "EC2 instance Type": "t2.large",
               }

    "Post_build_data": {

       "Serverenvironment": "Non-production",
       "AWSRegion: "USEast_NorthVirginia"
                }
},
"Server2":{

   "Build_data": { 
  
      "OSType": "Windows",
      "OSVersion": "Windows Server 2019",
      "EnvironmentTags": 
       {
         "Name": "sasaasasa",
         "Contact": "abc@gmail.com",
         "Owner": "NA",
        }
      "EC2 instance Type": "t2.large",
               }

    "Post_build_data": {

       "Serverenvironment": "Non-production",
       "AWSRegion: "USEast_NorthVirginia"
                }
}
So on 

}
```

Below code works fine to get the data for all the servers but I need this in the nested format. As this is something new to me, your ideas will be of great help! If I have missed anything or if some more information is required, please let me know. [csv image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Bb5.png)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Downloads/Three_servers_2022_06_16_18_50_04.csv',engine ='python',encoding= 'unicode_escape').dropna(how='all', axis=1).dropna(how='all')
df.replace("\u00a0","", inplace=True)
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1).fillna("NA")
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0])
df["NA"] = df["NA"].str.replace(' ', '')
df["NA"] = df["NA"].str.replace('*', '')
df["NA"] = df["NA"].str.replace('?', '')
df = df.rename(index= df["NA"]).drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1)
result = df.to_json('C:/Users/Downloads/check.json', orient="columns")
```

Comment: Redefining,  you df variable all the time isnt a good practice

Comment: Thank you @INGl0R1AM0R1 for your suggestion. I'll work on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_json method:

```
result = df.to_json(orient="records") # use index/reccords/columns that fits for you
parsed = json.loads(result)
json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thank you @Deb for considering. Using the above to_json method, I am getting the output in different lines; however, main requirement is to get the data in nested format within the server details. For eg: nested json for build and post build data as well as for the environment tags.